# Can Prism InvokeCommandAction be used with Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I got this error

> 'InvokeCommandAction' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'

Xaml file as below

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
xmlns:prismI="clr-namespace:Prism.Interactivity;assembly=Prism.Wpf"
```

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger  EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
        <prismI:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding testCmd}"/> ==> this line was error
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

NuGet installed package:

- Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf 1.1.19
- Prism.Unity 7.2.0.1422

I dont want to use MVVMLight and write behavious myself to use in `i:Interaction.Behavious`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The types in *Prism's* interactitvity namespace are based on the `System.Windows.Interactivity` assembly. It is shipped with *Blend for Visual Studio*. If you install it, you can find the assembly in the path below. Prism does **not contain** these assemblies, it only provides types based on it.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll
```

You could alternatively install the NuGet package *[System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/)*, but this package is **not official** so I do not recommend it.

To use the older assemblies in XAML, just replace the namespace declaration with this one.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

The *[Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf)* package is the open source variant that was released in December 2018. Since it ships different assemblies with different namespaces, it is incompatible with types based in the *Blend SDK* assemblies.

The good news is, that *Prism 8* will use the newer package, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and editing. By the way, are you  success update to Prism 8 yet? I cant update and no error pop out.

Comment: @dellos Prism 8 is available since a few days and introduces several breaking changes, so you will most likely adapt some of your code. You can refer to the [release notes](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v8.0.0.1909) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Prism 7.2.0.1422 brings it's own (old) version of the XAML Behaviors and you are mixing the new nuget package and the old version, that might be the issue. have you tried using

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding testCmd}"/>
```

thus replaceing `prismI` with `i`?

Comment: I used Prism to get EventArgs to command. note that prismI is deffirence name